# create index concurrently on partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-14

I am using postgresql 14.1, and I re-created my live database using parititons for some tables.

since i did that, i could create index when the server wasn't live, but when it's live i can only create the using `concurrently` but unfortunately when I try to create an index concurrently i get an error.

running this:

```
create index concurrently foo  on foo_table(col1,col2,col3));
```

provides the error:

```
ERROR:  cannot create index on partitioned table "foo_table" concurrently
```

now it's a live server and i cannot create indexes not concurrently and i need to create some indexes in order to improve performance. any ideas how do to that ?

thanks

Comment: Maybe you could get better answers to this [admin] question at dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No problem. First, use `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` to create the index on each partition. Then use `CREATE INDEX` to create the index on the partitioned table. That will be fast, and the indexes on the partitions will become the partitions of the index.

Comment: do i use the same name for the index ?

Comment: No, that is not even possible if the partitions are in the same schema. The names of the indexes won't matter, as long as the definition is the same.

Answer (score 7):

Step 1: Create an index on the partitioned (parent) table

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON ONLY foo (col1, col2, col3);
```

This step creates an invalid index. That way, none of the table partitions will get the index applied automatically.

Step 2: Create the index for each partition using `CONCURRENTLY` and attach to the parent index

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY foo_idx_1
  ON foo_1 (col1, col2, col3);
ALTER INDEX foo_idx
  ATTACH PARTITION foo_idx_1;
```

Repeat this step for every partition index.

Step 3: Verify that the parent index created at the beginning (Step 1) is valid. Once indexes for all partitions are attached to the parent index, the parent index is marked valid automatically.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_index WHERE pg_index.indisvalid = false;
```

The query should return zero results. If thats not the case then check your script for mistakes.

Comment: Also, the command `\d foo_idx` in `psql` shows if the index is _valid_ or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to postresql [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) in their example it says:

> Create an index on the key column(s), as well as any other indexes you might want, on the partitioned table. This automatically creates a matching index on each partition, and any partitions you create or attach later will also have such an index.

I follow this steps and it worked:

1. create parent table that you want partitioned
2. create partition tables
3. create index on the parent table for the columns used for partitioning

At the end you have the index on the parent table and on all partition tables too.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that I followed to create an index on a partitioned table.

1. Create a CONCURRENT index on all partitioned tables.
2. Once the index on all partitioned tables is done, run the create index on the parent table.

This process took around 40 minutes to complete.
Details of partition table.

1. Number of partitions  = 90.
2. Data in each partition = ~500k rows.
3. Cardinality of the column being indexed = ~25.

Details of database instance:

1. vCPUs = 4
2. RAM = 16GB
3. IOPS = 3000
4. PG version = 14.7