# What ONLY keyword really means in Postgresql CREATE INDEX command

Tags: postgresql

From the docs: "Indicates not to recurse creating indexes on partitions, if the table is partitioned. The default is to recurse.".

Am I understand correctly that index will not be created on existing partitons? What kind of index will be created then (on what)?

Comment: You should read further down in the page where you found that text, it explains it more fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objective is to build a partitioned index with as little locking as possible.

Normally, you'd use `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` to create an index on each partition, then `CREATE INDEX` on the partitioned table. If the index definitions match, the previously created indexes will become partitions of the partitioned index. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958090/6464308).

The potential problem with that is that all partitions will be locked at the same time. Instead, you can do it one partition at a time:

- create the index `ONLY` on the partitioned table (the index will be invalid)
- use `ALTER INDEX ... ATTACH PARTITION` to attach the indexes on the partitions as partitions of the index
- once all partitions are attached, the partitioned index will become valid

Answer (score 1):

> When CREATE INDEX is invoked on a partitioned table, the default
> behavior is to recurse to all partitions to ensure they all have
> matching indexes. Each partition is first checked to determine whether
> an equivalent index already exists, and if so, that index will become
> attached as a partition index to the index being created, which will
> become its parent index. If no matching index exists, a new index will
> be created and automatically attached; the name of the new index in
> each partition will be determined as if no index name had been
> specified in the command. If the ONLY option is specified, no
> recursion is done, and the index is marked invalid. (ALTER INDEX ...
> ATTACH PARTITION marks the index valid, once all partitions acquire
> matching indexes.) Note, however, that any partition that is created
> in the future using CREATE TABLE ... PARTITION OF will automatically
> have a matching index, regardless of whether ONLY is specified.

small demo example:

```
create table index_part (a int, b int) partition by range (a, b);
create table index_part1 partition of index_part for values from (0,0) to (10, 10);
create table index_part2 partition of index_part for values from (10,10) to (20, 20);
create index index_part_a_b_idx on only index_part (a, b);
```

now is INVALID:

```
\d+ index_part_a_b_idx
---
btree, for table "public.index_part", invalid
Partitions: index_part2_a_b_idx
Access method: btree

create index idxpart1_a_b_idx on index_part1 (a, b);
alter index index_part_a_b_idx attach partition idxpart1_a_b_idx;
```

still INVALID.

```
\d+ index_part_a_b_idx
---
btree, for table "public.index_part", invalid
Partitions: idxpart1_a_b_idx
Access method: btree
```

then

```
create index idxpart2_a_b_idx on index_part2(a, b);
alter index index_part_a_b_idx attach partition idxpart2_a_b_idx;
```

now ISVALID.

```
select indisvalid from pg_index  where indexrelid = 'idxpart2_a_b_idx'::regclass; ---return true.
```