# Create index on patitioned table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I tried to create indexes on a Postgres partitioned table which contains around 1.3 million rows. It contains data for the year 2023 and I partitioned it on the 'created_at' column which is of timestamp type. But still, when I try to query data for 2-3 months it's taking 3-4 minutes to return the resulting rows, and takes around 15-20 seconds if I query for 4-5 days of data. So I thought of creating an index on the parent table 'ticket_partition' which is further partitioned for every month having table names m1 to m11:
[Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9cLU.png)
I have come to know the below thread which explains how we can create an index on the partitioned tables:
[create index concurrently on partitioned table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958090/create-index-concurrently-on-partitioned-table)

Then I created index according to this and when I tried to merge the partitioned table's index to the parent table's index, it's saying 'relation "tkt_idx" does not exist' as shown in the below image

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUyCK.png)
Does anyone knows how we can resolve this error?
Also if you guys have any other way to improve the query performance i.e. retrieve data for 2-3 months within a minute then please share your thoughts as well.
Thanks

Tried Creating index on Partitioned tables and then attaching it to parent table's index but not working

Comment: Could you please share the external images in plain text in your question? And when having performance issues, please share the result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement, the SQL statement itself and the DDL for all tables and indexes involved. All in plain text, as an update to your question.